# Modulus of a number will always return between 0 and its number-1?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, modulus

I need to do a MOD of a number which is a `long datatype` with 1965.

Something like this -

```
number % 1965
```

Will the above modulus result always be within `0` and `1964`?

Or there are some cases in which it won't return any number between 0 and 1664?

I am using Java as programming language and I will be running my program on Ubuntu machines.

Initially I thought its a Math question but it depends mostly on the Compiler and Language... So kind of confused it will always return number between 0 and 1664 or there are some exception cases?

This is what I have in my method -

```
private static int getPartitionNumber() {
    return (int) (number % 1965);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

One thing I forgot to mention is, here `number` will always be positive number. Any negative number I am throwing IllegalArgumentException at the starting of the program.

Comment: If `number` is non-negative, this is true in pretty much every language. Some languages will return a negative result for a negative `number`; I'm not sure if this is the case in Java.

Comment: Are you sure you need to cast? I think modulus always returns whole numbers, not floating

Comment: @aliasm2k, Here number is a `long datatype` so I thought its better to cast it? Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: If it compiles without the cast you don't need the cast.

Comment: @ChrisHayes In Java, if `x` < 0 and `y` > 0, then `x % y` will be negative.  The Wikipedia entry for [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) has a cool chart that lists how this operation works in 88 different languages.  Some languages have two modulo operators that handle negative numbers differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, java's implementation of modulus will return a value in the range `(-n, n)` for the value `x % n`. I.e. If you have a negative number as the left operand, then the result will be negative. to get around this, try something like the following:

```
((x % n) + n) % n;
```

Which will return a value in the range `[0,n)`

**EDIT (to reflect UPDATE in question)**

In the case of positive numbers in the left operand, then simply `x % n` will produce numbers in the range `[0,n)` where `x >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I forgot to mention is, here `number` will always be positive number. Any negative number I am throwing IllegalArgumentException. This is the case with positive number as well?

Comment: If you can guarantee that the left operand (in the above example, `x`) is positive, then the result of `x % n` is guaranteed to be in the range `[0,n)` (You don't need to do the bit where you add an extra `n` and take another modulo).